# Orchard: theme placement not overriding module placement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am running Orchard 1.4.2. I have a custom theme based on an unmodified "The Theme Machine" installed and set as current.

My custom theme defines the following placement.info file:

```
<Placement>
    <Place Parts_Autoroute="-"/>
    <Place Parts_Autoroute_Edit="-"/>
    <Place Parts_Autoroute_SummaryAdmin="-"/>
    <Place Parts_Autoroute_Summary="-"/>
</Placement>
```

Am I correct in expecting the Autoroute part to be removed from all items when using this? The permalink and "set as home page" checkbox is still visible when I view content in the dashboard. If I make changes to the placement file in the modules themselves, it works fine.

Is there something I might be missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Your theme is not an admin theme, so when you are in the admin, that file is irrelevant.

If you want to remove the autoroute part, why don't you do just that and remove it from your types?

Comment: I don't want to remove it, I just don't want to display it to the user.

Comment: Well, your placement file is removing it from all places where it could be viewed or edited, so what's the point of still having it? In any case, your theme is not an admin theme so it won't work.

Comment: The difference is that I want to be able to navigate to a content item in the front-end by using the Autoroute part and not with the default content URL (i.e. `/event/my-test-event` and NOT `/content/12`) I want the functionality of the Autoroute part, I just don't want the user to edit it. And if the user can't edit it, what's the point in cluttering up the Dashboard with it? This seems like a common scenario, I don't believe that no-one else has had the same concerns.

Comment: But how are you going to set-up those URLs if you nobody, even you,can access the editor? It looks like what you want to use is Alias UI, not Autoroute.

Comment: Also note that there is a setting on Autoroute to not allow editing and just let the pattern deal with URL generation without user intervention.

Comment: In my module's Migration I set the pattern and the setting to not allow editing. I will have a look at Alias UI though.

Comment: As far as I can see the Alias UI module displays all the aliases set up by the autoroute feature. I don't want to have to manually go and set up each content item's alias, I want the autoroute feature to automatically define it based on the predefined patterns (as defined in my Migration). Is that not what the autoroute part is mainly used for? I don't want the user to define it, I want it automatically defined. All this is easy. My only issue is hiding the redundant (disabled) autoroute text box (preferably using the placement.info of my module).

Comment: Well, what you are asking for is a modification of the behavior of the autoroute module. You have two options: modify the module and submit your patch if you think that's how it should behave in the first place, or create your own module that behaves the way you want.

Comment: No I don't want to modify the behaviour of the autoroute module. In fact I think the entire Orchard system is just hunky dory (you get two thumbs up from me Bertrand). I am just trying to figure out how to use the placement file, because it sometimes behaves unexpectantly. On my one machine (at my office) the autoroute part is removed from the view as expected by doing the above, but at my home PC the exact same project (copied from svn repo) displays differently. Weird.

Comment: No but the same modules installed.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't play with the new admin based placement?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing in my CSS for the non-admin side was:

```
fieldset[shape-id='3']{display:none;}
```

Since my id was 3 and that is working for me. It would've been nice to have the option of having an autoroute, but when the option for "Allow custom patterns" is turned off that the Permalink box is not even shown.